# How does contenteditable work?

Tags: web-development, html, html5, browser

I recently came across an article where if you enter

```
data:text/html,%20<html contenteditable>
```

into the address bar of a browser that supports HTML5, you can type in the window.
I managed to figure out that with this you can basically write html in the address bar (it would be rather cumbersome) but
I do not understand how or why it works. What are the other functionalities of this command?

Comment: could you please point to the article you refer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first part - `data:text/html` - is a [Data URI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme) that tells the browser that what follows is html, and it should parse it.

The second part - `<html contenteditable>` - is the actual html, an editable html element. In HTML5 you can make any element editable with the [contentEditable attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Content_Editable).